# Loop through columns on google scripts

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I am looking to, with google scripts, loop through a number of input values and then copy paste value the resultant output values into another sheet with each new input iteration having the results pasted into successive columns.

I have managed to get the input vales to loop in an increment and to get the copy paste values to work in one column. However, I can't work out how to get the column that results are pasted into to loop (i.e. paste into column A, then B etc.).

I had a look on Stack Overflow, but could not find anything that appeared to answer this. My current code can be found below:

```
function ValueByOne() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange('Inputs!F3');
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  for (var cellValue = 1000; cellValue < 80000; cellValue += 1000){
  cell.setValue(cellValue + 1000);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange('CostComparison!D14:D27');
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet9!A1'), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
  }
```

It is specifically the `'Sheet9!A1'` that I want to loop. Such that when `cellValue` is 1000 it pastes to `'Sheet9!A1'` and when `cellValue` moves to 2000 it pastes to `'Sheet9!B1'`.

Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try a different approach when copying the files. Instead of using the copyTo function, try using copyValuesToRange, so you can iterate on the columns. The code should be something similar to this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cell = ss.getRange('Inputs!F3');
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  var resultsRange = ss.getRange('Results!A1:H1');
  var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results');
  for (var cellValue = 1000; cellValue < 80000; cellValue += 1000){
    cell.setValue(cellValue + 1000);
    var source = ss.getRange('CostComparison!D14:D27');
    var col = cellValue / 1000;
    source.copyValuesToRange( resultsSheet, col, col, 1, 10 );
  }
```